# MCU crystal capacitor selection

Tags: microcontroller, capacitor, avr, crystal

I will be using the [AT32UC3C2512C](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc32117.pdf), the [AVR32768 Application note](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc32157.pdf) recommends 22pF capacitors for crystals up to 16MHz...I will be using a 20MHz crystal, should I choose a 22pF or a 15pF loading capacitor?

EDIT:

As requested:

20MHz: [7B-20.000MEEQ-T](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/7B-20.000MEEQ-T/887-1303-1-ND/2207885)

16MHz: [ABM3B-16.000MHZ-10-1-U-T](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/ABM3B-16.000MHZ-10-1-U-T/300-8206-1-ND/687899)

Comment: can you please share the datasheets of the crystals, you are going to use, usually loading capacitor values are specified in datasheet, check this http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/75704/why-use-capacitors-with-crystals

Comment: Yes, I have all the values, but the formula in the MCU datasheet asks for the PCB capacitance also..which I have no clue...

Comment: The datasheet specifies the load cap to be 18pf for the ABM3B crystal

Comment: Related/similar: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/7807/2028 and http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/39103/2028

Comment: Also http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/14532/2028

Comment: @AnandKumarRai - No, it does not.  18pF is the default for the family, but the specific part linked is specified at 10pF.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A section on crystal oscillator characteristics is on page 1255 of the [AT32UC3C series datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc32117.pdf) (*complete* as opposed to *summary*).

[image: Excerpt from datasheet]

The value of C<sub>LEXT</sub> is based on the formula:

$$2(C_L - C_I) - C_{PCB}$$

The 20MHz crystal you selected, for example, has a 10pF load capacitance (\$C_L\$), denoted by the "Q" near the end of its part number (See the [part numbering reference](http://www.txccrystal.com/images/pdf/number-crystal-accuracy.pdf)). The internal equivalent load capacitance (\$C_I\$) is 1.7 pF (per page 1256 of the AT32UC3C datasheet). This leaves just the PCB (stray) capacitance (\$C_{PCB}\$) to be determined. That can get complicated, so we'll use a "[rule of thumb](http://www.adafruit.com/blog/2012/01/24/choosing-the-right-crystal-and-caps-for-your-design/)" of 5pF.

$$2(10 - 1.7) - 5 = 11.6pF$$

For more information see:

- Microchip: [Best Practices for PCB layout of oscillators](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/Appnotes/Atmel-8128-Best-Practices-for-the-PCB-Layout-of-Oscillators_ApplicationNote_AVR186.pdf)
- NXP: [Microcontroller Oscillator Circuit Design Considerations](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN1706.pdf)

Comment: A difference from 15pF to 11.6pF wont matter much right?

Comment: Possibly not. The stray capacitance of your board may vary by at least that amount, so you may just have to experiment. I think the Freescale document is most helpful for understanding/determining stray capacitance, but as I mentioned, it's complicated.

Comment: what are the results of a bad capacitor selection? Just inaccurate clock frequency or something else like no clock at all or erratic behaviour?

Comment: Frequency instability mostly, but no clock can also happen (the crystal will fail to resonate).

Comment: 10pF or 15pF, what do you think? (Honestly I don't think there is going to be any difference since Cstray is estimated)

Comment: Based on the math and the crystal's load capacitance, I'd use 10pF. But don't quote me on that, especially if you order up a thousand production units based on this. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to do this for a prototype don't even bother looking it up, either one will work.

If it's for production take a deeper look at the AT32UC3C2512C datasheet.

Comment: I already took a deep look...can't find a straight answer there...only if I know the PCB capacitance..which I dont..